# How to set CC/BCC by default on Laravel Mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail, mailtrap

I currently have an existing application that sends and email to a user. What I wanted to happen is that by default there should be a list of emails (from config file) attached to CC/BCC without manually setting `->cc` or `->bcc`. So whenever a mail is dispatched, the list of emails are automatically appended to that mail's CC/BCC.